# What's the difference between "sport facilities" and "modern equipment"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-difference

I'm reading the text about school now, please, help me to understand one of the sentences...

> "There are a lot of sport facilities and modern equipment in the gym".

What's the difference between "sport facilities" and "modern equipment" in this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sports facilities could include a running track, swimming pool, soccer/baseball/rugby/football fields, basketball court, and so on. Modern equipment in the gym probably refers to treadmills, weight-lifting equipment, etc.